# Terraform access other module specific value that has count function in another module

Tags: terraform

I have the following module that creates 3 subnets:

```
# AKS Subnet - Test / Staging / Production
module "aks_vpn_subnets" {
  source                  = "./modules/subnets"
  count                   = 3
  azure_subnet_name       = var.aks_azure_subnet_names[count.index]
  rg_name                 = module.rg.rg_name
  network_name            = module.network.name
  subnet_address_prefixes = [var.aks_subnet_address_prefixes[count.index]]
}
```

and `outputs.tf` and `main.tf` of the above subnet module is as follows:

`./modules/subnets`

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.azure_subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  virtual_network_name = var.network_name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}
output "subnet_id" {
  description = "ID of the subnet"
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet.*.id
}
```

Even though I create 3 subnets, I only need to create only 1 Kubernetes cluster (`AKS`) that is referencing only to the first subnet created from the above module.

```
# AKS cluster only create in the first subnet created?
module "aks_cluster" {
  source = "./modules/aks"

  count = 1

  . . . 

  vnet_subnet_id    = module.aks_vpn_subnet[count.index].subnet_id
  
  . . .

  depends_on = [
    module.aks_vpn_subnets
  ]
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

> The given value is not suitable for module.aks_cluster[0].var.vnet_subnet_id declared at
> │ modules/aks/variables.tf:47,1-26: string required.

here's `modules/aks/variables.tf`

```
variable "vnet_subnet_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "The ID of a Subnet where the Kubernetes Node Pool should exist"
}
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: You may want to index the subnet ids as well and grab only the first element: `module.aks_vpn_subnets[count.index].subnet_id[0]`

Comment: did you manage to fix this as I have exactly the same issue, my subnet module is making multiple subnets and I need to pass the IDs to another module.

Answer (score 0):

The situation you've described feels a little confusing because you have a module called "subnets" that seems to describe only one subnet, and then you use `count` with that module block to create multiple instances of it. Multiple instances of one module is a perfectly fine thing to do, but I would suggest renaming your directory to `./module/subnet` instead of `./module/subnets` to make it clearer that that module itself only describes one subnet. The repetition of the module is handled by the calling `module "aks_vpn_subnets"` block rather than by the module itself, and so the module has no awareness of it being instantiated multiple times.

Assuming I understood that correctly, I think your root problem here is that you've made your subnet module return a list of subnet IDs even though it's only managing one subnet. That means that `module.aks_vpn_subnets[count.index].subnet_id` is a list with one element instead of just a string, and so it doesn't match the type constraint for the `vnet_subnet_id` variable in your AKS module.

The main fix here would therefore be to change the output value to return just the one subnet ID directly as a string:

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = var.azure_subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  virtual_network_name = var.network_name
  address_prefixes     = var.subnet_address_prefixes
}

output "subnet_id" {
  description = "ID of the subnet"

  # NOTE: This is no longer using the splat operator
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
}
```

With just this change, `module.aks_vpn_subnets[count.index].subnet_id` should be just a string and so that should fix the error you saw.

Comment: This is not the answer I have the same issue.